# Uncaught Promise Rejection SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to log a arg to json but its giving me 0 error means it not getting input or undefined 
but in console.log it displays the args clearly what can i do ?

```
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
    name: "write",
    category: "fun",
    description: "Save 1 message in our database",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        let save = args.join(" ");
        console.log(save)

        let msgs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./message.json", "utf8"));

        msgs[message.guild.id] = {
            msgs: save
        };
        await fs.writeFile("./message.json", JSON.stringify(msgs), (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            message.channel.send("message logged");

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: your message.json probably isn't valid JSON and the call to JSON.parse fails

Comment: HAHAHA i see i was looking at wrong directory file i have 2 files by same name but in different dir xd the one this code was using was undefined in it instead of {} XD 
thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the message.json isn't a valid JSON. Instead, wrap the code in a try-catch so that error can be handled here. Also, try to log the ***msgs*** so that output can be viewed.

```
try {
 let msgs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./message.json", "utf8"));

 msgs[message.guild.id] = {
   msgs: save
 };
 await fs.writeFile("./message.json", JSON.stringify(msgs), (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  message.channel.send("message logged");
 }); 
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```